# MySQL Dynamic Pivot Table Select Most Recent Timestamp

Tags: mysql, pivot

I've been working with a dynamic pivot table in MySQL as referenced [here](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html), which works fine. In my situation, my table also has a timestamp column. I want to return the most recent values in the pivot table for the attributes and I can't figure out how to accomplish this. So consider the example table data:

```
+----+---------+---------------+--------+------------+
| id | item_id | property_name | value  | timestamp  |
+----+---------+---------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | color         | blue   | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |       1 | size          | large  | 2018-01-01 |
|  3 |       1 | weight        | 65     | 2018-01-01 |
<SNIP>
| 15 |       1 | color         | purple | 2018-02-01 |
| 16 |       1 | weight        | 69     | 2018-02-01 |
+----+---------+---------------+--------+------------|
```

For item_id '1' the result row should be:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| item_id | color  | size   | weight |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1 | purple | large  | 69     |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is slightly tricky.  We can use a subquery to find the most recent record for each item and property.  Then, join your table to this subquery and do a regular pivot query to generate the output you want.

```
SELECT
    t1.item_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.property_name = 'color'  THEN t1.value END) AS color,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.property_name = 'size'   THEN t1.value END) AS size,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.property_name = 'weight' THEN t1.value END) AS weight
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, property_name, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY item_id, property_name
) t2
    ON t1.item_id       = t2.item_id       AND
       t1.property_name = t2.property_name AND
       t1.timestamp     = t2.max_timestamp
WHERE
    t1.item_id = 1
GROUP BY t1.item_id;

item_id | color  | size  | weight
1       | purple | large | 69
```

### Demo